# Automatic rebuild/recompile of .Net Core 2.2 Web API after publishing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Whenever I deploy a newer version of my .Net Core 2.2 Web API, the first time the API is called by the consuming client (such as a GET), it takes a while for it to reply. Subsequent calls to the API are then fast. I believe this is because the first time a .Net Core web app is called, after the files having been updated, it has to do a quick re-build/re-compile (not sure what the correct term is).

Is there a way to get the API to be automatically re-built/re-compiled after publishing it? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rebuild/recompile here. The published app is *already* compiled. You haven't given us any information about your hosting situation, but some means of hosting will take longer than others to restart. For example, if your running in IIS, the App Pool literally shuts down and restarts, which takes some period of time. The app itself also has a startup period, namely running everything in `Program` and `Startup`. That should be relatively quick, but can be slower depending on what you're doing there. For example, if you're migrating your DB at startup (an antipattern, but one many people use), that's obviously going to add some time to the startup.

Also, .NET Core is a JITted runtime. The compilation process actually produces what's know as IL code. This IL code is then run on the runtime, just in time, hence JIT. However, the IL code can be constructed to optimize for different run scenarios. What's good for startup speed isn't necessarily good for steady-state performance and vice-versa. The runtime takes a balanced approach, optimizing for reasonable performance both on startup and steady-state. Starting with .NET Core 2.1, the idea of tiered compilation was introduced. It's complicated, but it essentially amounts to compiling the application twice: once for optimal startup and once for optimal steady state. Then, then the different compilations are swapped in or out depending on the status of the application. This enables faster startup and better steady-state performance. It has to be turned on with a tag in your project file, though, if you want to use it:

```
<TieredCompilation>true</TieredCompilation>
```

Finally, .NET Core 3.0 has made greater strides here, both in improving tiered compilation and in introducing the ability to [compile to native](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/Documentation/intro-to-corert.md). Native compilation removes the runtime entirely, so everything runs right on the metal. That's going to obviously give you the best performance, but it's also the most persnickety, as you have to compile for the *exact* destination, down to the architecture, OS, and even version. However, it's not yet available for ASP.NET Core apps. Still, it's something to keep on your radar.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Sorry, I didn't mention that I'm hosting the API on Azure, but I had the same issue when hosting on a Windows 2016 server. The first call to the API (after a publish) is always a lot slower then subsequent calls. And I'm pretty sure this happens even if I upload the API, wait, say, 10 minutes, and then call it. Which means that the API is only being restarted after the first call to it, and not immediately after a publish. Which maybe makes sense... I don't know. I just thought there might be an "automatic restart after publish" option, to avoid a slow first call by the client.

Comment: Azure doesn't tell us anything. Its like saying I'm hosting on hardware. Is it an app service, full VM, etc.?

Comment: I'm sorry Chris. It's an Azure App Service (running on an S1 Service Plan in the South Africa North region). But I noticed the same behaviour (of a slow first call to the API after a publish) when it was hosted on a Windows Server 2016 dedicated server at our ISP

Comment: But it's not a biggy. I was just curious really. I'm pretty sure what's happening is that, when publishing the API to the server, the API is stopped. Then, when a client does a call to the API, that starts the API service (which is why it takes longer than usual). After that, the API is running, and subsequent calls are quick.

Comment: I read this "Because ASP.NET Core apps run in a process separate from the IIS worker process, the module handles process management. The module starts the process for the ASP.NET Core app when the first request arrives and restarts the app if it shuts down or crashes." here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2 (in the "Out-of-process hosting model" section) - so I'm thinking maybe my assumption that the API is only being restarted after the first request arrives (after a publish), and is not automatically restarted after the publish, is right?

Comment: Late, i know, but maybe it's helpful for someone else: go to the App Services Settings / Configuration -> General Settings -> Enable "Always On" 

More Info: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086196